# Find table names having a particular value in 'any columns'

Tags: mysql

I was looking for this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443422/how-to-find-in-all-the-tables-containing-columns-having-particular-values) to find my solution. But this one deals with when the column name is known. But in my case the column name is unknown. i.e. it can be col1, col2, or colN.

Right now I only have the table names from my database using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db_name';
```

Now with another query(joining together) I want to scan the tables for all the columns that match the given value. Is it possible with MySql using any built-in function? Or Can any sql tweaking do this trick?

Comment: How many tables do you have and how big is your DB? If this is one time activity and based on DB we can do something I guess

Comment: @cjg its having around 100 tables. Average count for the tables are 15-20 records. Each tables are having average 10-15 columns.

Comment: And its one time activity?

Comment: @cjg Yes right now onetime. But in future we may use it again. I can easily do the `mysqldump` into a txt file and then can use a search. But preferring to have a solution pragmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If its one time activity, why cant you run a query to generate the query that give you result.

I dont know a better solution :)

Queries will be something like:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 100000;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
CONCAT( 'select "',TABLE_NAME,'.',COLUMN_NAME, '" from `',TABLE_NAME,'` where `', COLUMN_NAME, '` in ("val0", "val1") limit 1') 
SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ' ) as query
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db_name' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/queries.sql' \G
```

Now you can run source the file.

```
SOURCE /tmp/queries.sql;
```